# SVN Merge Branch from one Repo into Trunk of other Repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I have two repositories which live on separate servers, call them repo-1 and repo-2.

To start both "trunks" were equal:

repo-1/trunk == repo-2/trunk

Meanwhile changes were being commited to repo-1/trunk and I was working on and commiting changes to repo-2/trunk.

Now I need to merge changes from repo-1/trunk into repo-2/trunk.

I thought I would copy repo-1/trunk into repo-2/tags/r1_20090224, then merge that tag into my local working copy of repo-2/trunk (i.e. c:\dev\repo2-trunk).

Any suggestions on how to do this?  I'm trying to use TortoiseSVN and performing "Merge two different trees", I used the following settings:

From: repo-2/trunk
To: repo-2/tags/r1_20090224
Working Copy: c:\dev\repo2-trunk

I also tried swapping the "from" and "to"...but no luck.  By trying either of those two merge options I either end up with the following outcome:

1. If I merge from trunk to tag (into my local copy of repo-2/trunk) I lose my trunk changes and get the tag changes.
2. If I merge from tag to trunk (into my local copy of repo-2/trunk) I lose my tag changes and keep my trunk changes.

Any suggestions on to do this??

Comment: @codecraig, have you found a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First figure out the revision where the trees were the same. Then merge that from that revision to HEAD of the repo-1 repository to your repo-2 working copy.

Using the commandline client it's similar to this, if you want to merge changes between r123 and r456

```
svn merge http://domain.tld/repos1@123 http://domain.tld/repos1@456 repos2-workingcopy
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, but you need to merge from the *base* of the two trees, i.e. the point at which the two trunks were the same.

Sander beat me to it, so credit to him, but here are a couple more tips:

1. Get these two repositories joined up into one as soon as possible; Subversion wasn't really designed to work like this. Or alternatively move to a DVCS like git or bazaar or ...
2. If you stick with Subversion, conventionally this kind of stuff is done with *branches*, not *tags*. Tags are normally used as marker points, and are not committed to.

Answer (score 1):

**If** `svn merge` were to fail you across the two sites/servers:

```
svn: Unusable URI: it does not refer to this repository
```

Then use the following approach:

1. *identify the revision level at which `repo-2` started diverge from `repo-1`, say 123*, then:
2. `svn co http://server1/repo-1/trunk`
3. `svn diff -r123:HEAD http://server2/repo-2/trunk >repo2.patches`
4. `patch -p0 -i repo2.patches`
5. *screen for any conflicts and resolve them*
6. `svn ci --message "merged from repo-2"`

Comment: So the two repo's don't share any history.  For example, repo-1/trunk existed for some time.

then repo-2/trunk was created by doing the following:
    1. export repo-1/trunk and burned to a CD
    2. CD is taken to repo-2 server and merely "added" as repo-2/trunk

Answer (score 0):

[SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage) might be able to help if you find yourself constantly managing multiple repositories over time that need to be synced every once in a while.